# OS X Server legacy support

Tags: osx-lion, user-profiles, osx-server, osx-yosemite

I've been searching for some time but haven't come across an answer to this seemingly simple question: If you have a Mac server running the latest release (Server App, Yosemite), how old can the OS X release on a client Mac be and still be able to access network accounts?

For example: could a MacBook 3,1 running OS X 10.7.x access network accounts served from a Yosemite Server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just called Apple support, stepped through the hoops, and the answer turns out to be 10.6.x. Hope that saves someone a phone call!